# Why Jmeter RandomString function always return Unicode characters

Tags: jmeter

In my test plan I used ${__RandomString(5)} function in my Post request to make it dynamic. Script run successfully But the problem is It always return Unicode CJK characters and some time it return string which ultimately throws error and script execution fails for large request.
Error: 
'\u0018', hexadecimal value 0x18, is an invalid character."

can any one have any work around to generate string with English characters. Or any settings that I need to changes to return english characters in RandomString function.

Comment: So did you look at the JMeter documentation? I'd guess this function is simply chaining random numbers.

Comment: Yes I go through Jmtere documentation and also try other function to generate  Dynamic data but no luck. I just wonder about why I my getting Unicod text in my RendomString function. Is it related to my system settings? or any other reason?

Comment: The function description literally says “can be readable or not”. It’s generating random bytes, because in the end, that’s what characters are.